# MySQL subquery WHERE IN

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause, where-in

I have this query below and ran it, but it kept saying I have a different version of `MySQL`?
I think the problem is WHERE IN and its subquery.

Can anyone help me?

```
SELECT Field2, Field3, Count(Distinct Field1)
FROM learning.master
WHERE Field3 IN 
(SELECT Field3, COUNT(Distinct Field1)
FROM learning.master_06302015
WHERE (Field2 IS NOT NULL AND Field3 IS NOT NULL AND Field7 IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY Field3
ORDER BY COUNT(Distinct Field1)
LIMIT 10)
Group BY Field2, Field3;
```

Comment: Yes, there's a problem is in the subquery. The subquery should return a *single* expression (column).

Comment: What if I have the same tables for both main query and subquery?

Comment: SELECT Field2, Field3, Count(Distinct Field1)
FROM learning.master_06302015
WHERE Field3 IN 
(SELECT Field3
FROM learning.master_06302015
WHERE (Field2 IS NOT NULL AND Field3 IS NOT NULL AND Field7 IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY Field3
ORDER BY COUNT(Distinct Field1) DESC
LIMIT 10;)
Group BY Field2, Field3
;

Comment: qualify *all* column references with a table alias.  `SELECT t.Field1 FROM mytable t`. Just use a different alias for each reference. See the example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Use a join operation rather than a `WHERE IN` when there's a LIMIT involved in the subquery.

(edit strikes out first part of original answer. Thank you Gordon for pointing that out.)

<strike>Just remove this expression **`, COUNT(Distinct Field1)`** from the SELECT list of the subquery.</strike>

---

Like this:

```
 SELECT t.Field2
      , t.Field3
      , COUNT(DISTINCT t.Field1) 
   FROM learning.master t
  WHERE Field3 IN ( SELECT o.Field3
                      FROM learning.master_06302015 o
                     WHERE o.Field2 IS NOT NULL 
                       AND o.Field3 IS NOT NULL
                       AND o.Field7 IS NOT NULL
                     GROUP BY o.Field3
                     ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT o.Field1) 
                     LIMIT 10
                  )
  GROUP BY t.Field2, t.Field3
```

or, use a join operation, like this:

```
 SELECT t.Field2
      , t.Field3
      , COUNT(DISTINCT t.Field1) 
   FROM learning.master t
   JOIN ( SELECT o.Field3
            FROM learning.master_06302015 o
           WHERE o.Field2 IS NOT NULL 
             AND o.Field3 IS NOT NULL
             AND o.Field7 IS NOT NULL
           GROUP BY o.Field3
           ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT o.Field1) 
           LIMIT 10
        ) p
     ON p.Field3 = t.field3   
  GROUP BY t.Field2, t.Field3
```

Comment: I don't think the first works in MySQL (which doesn't allow `LIMIT` in certain subqueries).  The second should be fine, though.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: You are right. MySQL returns Error code:1235 "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANYSOME subquery'". My answer is edited to strike out the first recommendation for SQL. Use the JOIN operation instead.